# Generating start and end points for LineStrings

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, linestring

I want to create start and endpoints in QGIS for a Linestring shapefile.

I tried using the ["QChainage Plugin"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/) but was not useful.

Can someone suggest a tool?

[image]

Answer (score 21):

If you have QGIS 3.4 you can use `Extract specific vertices tool` to extract the endpoints by inputting `0, -1` at the vertex indices as you can see below:

[image]

The tool is located in `Processing toolbox -> Vector geometry -> Extract specific vertices tool`.

The input is a polyline composing of several segments

[image]

Using the above tool with `0,-1` indices provides the endpoints only:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can also use a **Virtual layer** (Data Source Manager > Virtual Layer) with SQL:

```
select id, st_endpoint(geometry) as geometry from lineshp
union
select id, st_startpoint(geometry) as geometry from lineshp
```

Comment: The virutal layer query saves the `start` and `end points` in single colomn. Can we save them in two different coloumns?

Comment: Yes, but QGIS can only load one geometry column at a time, so you will only see either start or end point, if you drop the union clause.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use expressions `start_point()` and `end_point()` to create start- and endpoints of your lines. Use this expression to get both at once:

```
union (
    end_point ( $geometry ),
    start_point ( $geometry )
)
```

Paste this expression on an additional symbol layer on your line layer to create points for visualization purpose only (see screenshot) or create a new layer with actual point geometries using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression` and using the same expression.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the GRASS tool `v.to.points` for this. Select `node` and adjust `minimum distance`.

Answer (score 2):

Use these expressions in the attribute table:

- x_min($geometry)
- y_min($geometry)
- x_max($geometry)
- y_max($geometry)

As easy as that.