# Generate node / vertex at starting point of line connections

Tags: qgis, intersection, extract, vertices, nodes

I have line and point layer. I connected line layer with points using `connect nodes to line` in `processing toolbox`. After creating a connection line (green color), I used `line intersection from processing toolbox` to extract the nodes/vertex of each starting point of the connection line as shown in red color. The problem here is:

- The `line intersection` generates nodes for every intersection of line as circled with black color in image. I only want to extract nodes of lines which connect point and a line layer.
- I also tried `Extract specific vertices tool` as suggested in previous questions ([here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306190/generate-start-and-end-points-in-qgis-for-linestrings)), but it does the same thing as `line intersection` function.

[image]

Comment: May be you can first select the lines which have a blue point connection and then make your intersection only on the selected lines, which will avoid intersections with red-red.

Comment: You say you have a point and a line layer and than connect nodes to line, thus you create another line. However, on your screenshot I see only one line layer. Can you explain? As well, I can't find a tool in the tollbox named `connect nodes to line` - which one are you using?

Answer (score 2):

the tool 'Extract specific vertices' can fit your demand. but you must set parameter 'vertex indices' to '0,-1' telling the program to choose the first point and the last point