# Generating start and end points for individual road segments

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, virtual-layer, geometry-generator

I have shape file with road network (line layer) as shown in Image 1. The road network contains multiple line segments as shown with blue line in image.

- I am trying to generate `start` and `end point` of every road segment.
- Save the start and end point in a seperate layer.

Based on the suggested answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306190/generating-start-and-end-points-for-linestrings/306204), I am trying to get the start and end points by using query in **virtual layer**

**Problem**:It merges start and end points into single colomn. I am trying to get them in seperate coloumns. For instance, `Col 1: start points, Col2: end points`

```
select From_id, st_startpoint(geometry) as geometry from lineshp 
union
select To_id, st_endpoint(geometry) as geometry from lineshp
```

Attempt with geometry generator:

**Problem:** It only displays the start and end points. It does not save the data in seperate layer.

```
union (
    end_point ( $geometry ),
    start_point ( $geometry )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the virtual layer, you can compute both start and end point in a single row. Beware that your layer will now have 2 geometry fields, which are a pain to display (the 1st one is **usually** used)

```
SELECT From_id, st_startpoint(geometry) as geometryFrom, 
       To_id, st_endpoint(geometry) as geometryTO 
FROM lineshp
```

Comment: Thank you for great answer. I was wondering if the existing road network shapfile (TR_ROAD) has already `start and end points` as I can see `FROM_UFI` and `TO_UFI` in the attribute table https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sCzW.png. Are these are `start` and `end points`?  as the road network shapefile is available here https://drive.google.com/drive/u/2/folders/1-DKB4bGSYzgrP2Za2FWdmO-tBJBsU1oT

Answer (score 1):

you could just use the Vector->Geometry Tools->Extract Verctices tool to make an output of all vertices.

Then you could use a Select by expression to get the min and max vertices:

```
"vertex_ind" = maximum("vertex_ind", group_by:="[your_id_field]")
OR
"vertex_ind" = 0
```

Then export the selected features as a new shapefile.

You can add the coordinates to a new field using the formula:

```
x($geometry)
```

and

```
y($geometry)
```

Comment: Does the coordinate means Latitude and Longitude?. Does the formmula will save 4 points for start and end points? For instance, • START_X: X-coordinate of line start• START_Y: Y-coordinate of line start, • END_X: X-coordinate of line end, • END_Y: Y-coordinate of line end. Something similar to here in ArcGis https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012326

Comment: This would create 1 point for the end point and 1 point for the start point (2 points total). Do it twice and it will create 4 points total.  You can print the x and y values in any system you want - just reproject the data or use the 'transform()' function in your codeblock

Comment: I run the extract specific vertices tool by selecting 0 and -1 for the start and end points as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP08p.png. It only displays 0,1,-1 etc. Is it possible convert these into unique ids  such as `start point:61543`, `edpoint:78654`

Answer (score 0):

Run the extract specific vertices tool. Select 0 and -1 for the start and end points to be created as a point layer. Join attributes by location to get both point datasets into the same layer.

Comment: The specific vertices tool only saves 0 and -1 in the attribute table. I need information of start and end points with ids such as `start point:61543`, `edpoint:78654`