# Adding a new column with value in a virtual layer query

Tags: qgis, sql, virtual-layer

I've created start and end points from a LineString layer using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/306234/186820) from another question:

```
select id, sts as route_id, st_endpoint(geometry) as geometry from pointclasstest
union
select id, sts as route_id, st_startpoint(geometry) as geometry from pointclasstest
```

According to the comments to that post, using `union` is the only option to show both start and endpoints at the same time.

Now I am looking for a way to still seperate start and end points from each other within the layer via an added attribute,
e. g. start=1, end=2

**Is there a possibility to create a new field via SQL query when creating the layer and writing a given value into it?**

I've read into adding columns via SQL, but they all refer to an already existing table (`ALTER TABLE`, `ADD`, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add it with a fixed value and give it a name:

```
select id, sts as route_id, st_endpoint(geometry) as geometry, 1 as something from pointclasstest
union
select id, sts as route_id, st_startpoint(geometry) as geometry, 2 as something from pointclasstest
```

Comment: You were so fast ^_^. Great answer anyway!

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you!
sometimes I just don't see it even though it is so obvious